# Weak closure of intersection in reflexive Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, nonlinear-analysis, galerkin-methods

Let $X$ be a reflexive Banach space. Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a family of finite-dimensional subspaces of $X$. Consider a bounded sequance $(x_Y)_{Y\in \mathcal{S}}\subset X$. Define
$$C_Y=\bigcup_{Y'\supseteq Y, Y'\in \mathcal{S}}\{x_{Y'}\}.$$
How to prove that 
$$\bigcap_{Y\in \mathcal{S}}\overline{C_{Y}}^{\,w}\neq \emptyset\quad?\qquad (1)$$

First, observe that there exists $M>0$ large enough such that $C_Y\subset \overline{B_M}$. I considered a family $\mathcal{F}=\{C_Y\,|\, Y\in \mathcal{S}\}$. Pick $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and take $Y_1, Y_2,..., Y_n \in \mathcal{S}$. Without a loss of generality we may assume that 
$$Y_1\subseteq Y_2\subseteq... \subseteq Y_n.$$
Then, we have
$$C_{Y_n}\subseteq...\subseteq C_{Y_2}\subseteq C_{Y_1}$$
and so $\bigcap_{i=1}^nC_{Y_i}\neq \emptyset$. Now, from finite intersection property $\bigcap_{Y\in \mathcal{S}}C_{Y}\neq \emptyset$. Does it imply (1)? Is really reflexivity needed?

Comment: Is $S$ countable? Are the subspaces in $S$ increasing/decreasing? Otherwise $C_Y = \{x_Y\}$ would be possible.

Comment: $\mathcal{S}$ is not necessarily countable. However, we may assume, without loss of generality that subspaces in $\mathcal{S}$ are increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give a counterexample in $X = \ell^2$. We consider the unit sequences $\{e_n\}$, $Y_n = \operatorname{span}(e_n)$, $S = \{Y_1,Y_2,\ldots\}$ and $x_{Y_n} = e_n$.

Then, $C_{Y_n} = \{e_n\}$ and thus
$$
\bigcap_{Y \in S} \overline{C_Y}^w = \emptyset.
$$

Comment: Nice counterexemple! Can you please tell me how can we get the weak closedness of $C_{Y_n} = \{e_n\}$ ( I don't see that this can be a separate question) thank you :)

Comment: Finite subsets are always weakly closed. This is easy to check.

Answer (score 0):

For any $Y\in \mathcal{S}$ we know that $C_Y\subseteq\overline{B_M}$ for sufficiently large $M>0$. From Kakutani theorem we know that $\overline{B_M}$ is weakly compact. Pick $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and let $Y_1,...,Y_n\in \mathcal{S}$. Consider $$\overline{C_{Y_i}}^{\, w}$$ for $i=1,...,n$. Since $\overline{C_{y_i}}^{\,w}$ are weakly closed and 
$$\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}\overline{C_{Y{i}}}\neq \emptyset,$$
then from finite intersection property we obtain (1).